# Find the login name of the computers in the network using SNMP in Java

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j, oid

I am using **SNMP4J** library, using this I listed all the devices(printer, unix system, windows7, 8 systems) connected in my network.

I can get the details such as  uptime, name of the device.

From this, how can I get the login user name of that system??
I am searching any **OID** for that?? Is there any thing available for that or how can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

A system has no responsibility to expose its login information over SNMP. In fact, doing so seems to me like it would be a huge security liability.

If you are a system administrator, and need to keep track if which user names and passwords can be used to log in to machines in your network, you'll have to keep it in some form of secure database. Enterprise solutions for this exist, generally, as a feature of a Network Inventory system. For smaller networks, sysadmins have come up with all sorts of ad-hoc solutions, sometimes involving a printed list in a locked safe...

Comment: Well, excuse me if this sounds strange, but I'd suggest that you start by being the person who installs the machines, and you write down what user name and password you set when you install them...